# How to solve - Jenkins ERROR: Server rejected the private key(s) for slave

Tags: jenkins

If anybody faced this issue - Jenkins ERROR: Server rejected the private key(s) for slave.please provide some solution

Comment: Please be more precise... What dop you want to do? You want to connect a slave on your master? Is it a Windows or a Linux platform? Next, we will be able to help you.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try to connect Linux slave with master using ssh private key credential

Comment: I think it's preferable to generate a public key on the master and to register this public key in in the .ssh/authorized_keys file on the slave (for the jenkins account).

Comment: Issue got solved. I just used alternate option(Username with password) to connect linux slave with master.

Comment: OK, thanks for the update.

Comment: @BrunoLavit: Facing same issue while launching mac slave. Jenkins hosted on Linux machine and trying to launch it from mac m/c using Java web start method. Failed to launch wrapped exception
java.net.UnknownHostException: *hostname*

Comment: @Mahi,  Facing same issue while launching mac slave. Jenkins hosted on Linux machine and trying to launch it from mac m/c using Java web start method. Failed to launch wrapped exception java.net.UnknownHostException: hostname

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solved.

Because of insufficient permission I faced the above mentioned issue.
Now I can use both options.(SSH Username with private key , Username with password)

Comment: Insufficient permission where?
You are not providing any solution

Comment: Insufficient permission in linux slave machine. (only read permission)

Comment: I've had issues where the jenkins user did not have sufficient permissions on the .ssh folder, solved with chmod 700 .ssh.

Answer (score 0):

For me it just started happening after previously, successfully setting up the slave and SSH connection. The solution was to Disconnect the slave from the master and then reconnect it and it started working again.